# discord.py - how to make a command that takes many words with spaces as one argument

Tags: discord.py

I'd like to make a command like this:

```
async def offer(self,ctx,firstName=None,lastName=None,pitch=None):
```

and I want `pitch` to take every character including spaces after the `lastName` argument.
An example: I want `!offer Ocean Man Hi, join my team!` to assign "Ocean" to `firstName`, "Man" to `lastName`, and "Hi, join my team!" to `pitch`. I have been thinking this over for days now with no progress, and I can't seem to google the right thing as I usually do when I get stuck. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `*` like this: `async def offer(self,ctx,firstName=None,lastName=None, *, pitch=None):`. This will work for you.

Comment: How does that work? Won't everything just be assigned to `*`, which is... nothing? // Anyway, how do I make it into a string with spaces?

Comment: When you do that, if you type like
`!offer Ocean Man join my team!` this will return you `firstName=Ocean`, `lastName=Man`, `pitch=join my team!`. That `*` means that `pitch` will have all the words.after `lastName`.

Comment: if I want two args before the `*` to be optional, can i make the * start after a certain symbol? so, `!offer "Join my team!"`, right now it would assign `"Join` to `firstName`... how can I make `pitch` = everything after a quotation?

Comment: I couldn't understand your question, can you explain it better?

Comment: Yes. Right now, with this code, when I input `!offer Ocean "Join my team!"`, it will assume `"Join` is `lastName`. How do I make the arg `lastName` empty IF the next word starts with this character: `"`? I've tried this:

    `if lastName.startswith('"'):`

        `pitch = str(lastName) + str(pitch)`

        `lastName = ''`

but it doesn't work.